# Proper way to eat biscuit

Tags: food

When I bite biscuit it breaks into two large parts perpendicular to my mouth and it becomes difficult to eat those two large parts so what could be done to prevent it?

Here is what I want to say:

[image: Diagram]

Red line is how it was supposed to break and black line shows how it really breaks.

Comment: This is an XY problem.  You are attempting to eat a biscuit when you really want a [Twinkie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkie).  Because Twinkies are made of rubberlike compounds and delicious goo, they cannot break into pieces.  Problem solved.  Happiness restored.

Comment: The purpose of a biscuit is to be dunked in tea.  Then they do not break.

Comment: @Chenmunka So true, but once again, inferior to a Twinkie, which is impervious to tea.

Comment: Dang. Now I need to go and raid the tin of Christmas biscuits. All in the name of science, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it breaks, do the sides fold up or down?
If up, I suspect that your lower canines are slightly higher than the lower incisors (not unusual), meaning that the upward pressure is greater at the sides than at the middle.

You might try changing the "angle of attack" by holding the front of the biscuit higher (or lower).

Or perhaps swing it to one side (or the other) and bite it with only your right (or left) teeth.

If that doesn't work, an almost guaranteed solution is to dunk it into your tea or coffee first.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem, but I ate a chocolate digestive not the ordinary one shown, and thought the chocolate acts as reinforcement. I never considered the shape of the teeth.

Answer (score 4):

My **hack** is to first break the biscuit in two deliberately by hand.

Then bite into a half biscuit.

If, as Ray Butterworth supposes, it is the shape of your teeth causing a biscuit fracture, then the shorter width of a half-biscuit might not cause the same problem.